# Dropdown menu Isnt Working when i click a button

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, web-development-server

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropdownbutton">Select Algorithm
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <p>Link 1</p>
                  <p>Link 2</p>
                  <p>Link 3</p>
                </div>
              </button>
            </div>
```

I'm Trying to Use a button and when i click the button it should open a dropdown menu but I'm Unable to Do it. Button Click is Happening but the Dropdown menu is not working.

**Help Needed**

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simole code with js and css like this :

------------------------- Css Code-----------------------

```
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown-content.show {
        display: block;
    }
```

------------------------ HTML Code ------------------------

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdownbutton" onclick="showDropDown()">Select Algorithm
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Link 1</p>
        <p>Link 2</p>
        <p>Link 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

------------------------- JS Code-----------------------

```
    function showDropDown() {
        let drp = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
        drp.classList.contains('show') ?
            document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.remove("show") :
            document.querySelector(
                '.dropdown-content').classList.add("show")
    }
```